# cypress doesn't recognize the element I'm trying to find by placeholder

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

The element:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What's this article about?" >
```

How did I identify:

```js
cy.get("input[placeholder=`What's this article about?`]").type("<3");
```

The error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `input[placeholder=What's this article about?]`

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
cy.get("input[placeholder=\"What's this article about?\"]").type("<3");
```

or this with less escape characters:

```
cy.get('input[placeholder="What\'s this article about?"]').type("<3");
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. Try this

```
cy.get('input[placeholder*="Your Placeholder Text"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is much cleaner:

```js
cy.get('input').should('have.attr', 'placeholder', 'Your Placeholder Text')
```

That way, in your error messages you will be able to distinguish between the case where the input element does not exist and whether it has a wrong placeholder. The previous examples will return the same error in both cases.

Also, if you want to run the same test on different inputs such as texture etc. you can immediately see where the 'texture' query word should go.

And one more thing. Instead of using the placeholder to find the UI element, it is much better practice to just give it a data-cy attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be to use the `[attribute*=value]` selector. This selects every element whose attribute value contains the substring of the original string. So in your case it could be `[placeholder*="article"]` or `[placeholder*="article about"]`, basically you can add any substring you want.

**Word of caution** - This should only be used when you know for sure that the occurrence of the sub string that your are searching for is once, that is your target element.

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder*="article about"]').type('<3')
```

Or if you have multiple occurrences, then you have to use `eq` to reach that element.